# Improve Jquery code implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm working with jquery and this code is working but I wanto to improve it because I'm not re-using code. Theres a way to dinamically sent `$("#btn_step1")` changing the number oh the step?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-1");
    var body = $("html, body");

    activeDiv.siblings().hide();
    $("#btn_step1").on("click", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        activeDiv.hide();
        activeDiv.next().show();
        activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-2");

        body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');

    });
    $("#btn_step2").on("click", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        activeDiv.hide();
        activeDiv.next().show();
        activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-3");

        body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');
    });
    $("#btn_step3").on("click", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        activeDiv.hide();
        activeDiv.next().show();
        activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-4");

        body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using the attribute [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
// get all elements with id's that start with btn_step
$("[id^='btn_step']").on("click", function( event ){        
    activeDiv.hide();
    activeDiv.next().show();
    activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-" + (+this.id.replace('btn_step','') + 1));
    body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');
});
```

or give them a similar class

```
$(".theClass").on("click", function( event ){        
    activeDiv.hide();
    activeDiv.next().show();
    activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-" + (+this.id.replace('btn_step','') + 1));
    body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');
});
```

Looking at the code more you can actually just do this

```
$(".theClass").on("click", function( event ){
    activeDiv = activeDiv.hide().next().show();       
    body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use classes for the `btn_steps`instead of individual IDs.
Using classes you could use one single function that is fires once a `.btn_step` element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that's changing is a number so something like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-1"),
        body = $("html, body"),
        steps = 4,
        i = 0;


    activeDiv.siblings().hide();

    for (i; i < steps; i++) {
        var selector = "#btn_step" + i;

        $(selector).on("click", function( event ){
            event.preventDefault();
            activeDiv.hide();
            activeDiv.next().show();

            activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-" + (i + 1));

            body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of code duplication, given that you are performing the same operation on elements with three different `id` attributes. Consider adding a class `btn_step` to each of the elements `btn_step1`, `btn_step2`, and `btn_step3`. Then, keep track of what `step` you are on when assigning the `click` function to each element of the `btn_step` class:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var body = $("html, body");

    $(".btn_step").each(function(index, element) {
        element.click(function() {
            var step = index + 1;

            event.preventDefault();

            var activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-" + step);
            activeDiv.siblings().hide();
            activeDiv.hide();
            activeDiv.next().show();
            activeDiv = $("#mod_formSteps-2");

            body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');
        });
    });
};
```